# Someone who gives an answer for the sake of an answer

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

How would you define an act or a person who answers a question with an answer they know might not necessarily be true, for the sake of providing one?

eg.

Tim - What's the name of Microsoft's new operating system?
Bob - Ermmm. Windows 9.
Tim - Thanks Bob.

Comment: This is unclear. Can you elaborate? Also, is there such a a word in your native language and you're looking for a translation or so you just hope there is such a word in English?

Comment: Sure! English is my native language, I'm unsure if such a word exists. Bob may or may not know the answer to the question Tim's asking, but regardless on whether the information is true, Bob has still provided an answer for the sake of answering the question.  

What does this make Bob? Or how would you express Bob's actions?

Comment: @Aeyz Maybe, "he has an answer for everything."

Comment: Must... resist... urge to give... bad... answer!

Comment: Sometimes people want to appear smarter than they actually are, so they give what they know is (or could be) a wrong answer at the risk of appearing stupid if they are caught! Some folks are funny that way. Call it insecurity, or neediness, or starved for attention, or whatever.  Don

Comment: Bob has failed to heed the advice of the old adage “**It’s Better to Remain Silent and Be Thought a Fool than to Speak and Remove All Doubt**.”  Some might describe people like Bob (& others who just find silence awkward, don’t appreciate it, & who think that their awkward utterances are preferable to it) as being “blurters” or “spouters,” practicing the fine art of “blurting” & “spouting.”  Usually “utter/random nonsense” is blurted/spouted by such people, but in Bob’s defense, there is some logic to his answer so he’s actually “blurting/spouting out the first thing that came to [his] mind."

Answer (score 5):

If a person with a normal attitude receives a question to which he/she doesn't have an answer to, a reply would be "I have no idea. Why don't you look up the internet?" or "I don't know."

Know-it-all is the word describing;

A person who behaves as if they know everything

from Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary.

Someone who thinks he knows everything and refuses to accept advice or information from others.

from Thesaurus

Know-it-all can be used as an adjective.

[8 Tips for dealing with a know-it-all coworker](http://www.forbes.com/sites#/sites/jacquelynsmith/2013/09/09/8-tips-for-dealing-with-a-know-it-all-coworker).

Comment: Sadly not what I'm trying to find. Though a very interesting (and eerily relevant) article!

Comment: @Aeyz Good luck. It was just a suggestion. There are more words suggested in other links and above. It's not a thing to feel sad about.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're describing a ***[charlatan](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/charlatan)***

> a person who pretends or claims to have more knowledge or skill than he or she possesses; quack.

Comment: I never actually knew the meaning of the word! Every day is a school day. This feels warmer to what I'm trying to describe but still no cigar. Another similar one was elusively concise.